# ActiveChoiceReactive parameteriation not works

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

```py
def call() {
    def envChoices = input(
        message: 'Select the Environment:',
        parameters: [
            [$class: 'ChoiceParameter',
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
            description: 'Select the Environment',
            name: 'Env',
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript',
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [],
                    sandbox: false,
                    script:
                        'return[\'Could not get Env\']'
                ],
                script: [
                    classpath: [],
                    sandbox: false,
                    script:
                        'return["Dev","QA","Stage","Prod"]'
                ]
            ]
            ]
        ]
    )

    def serverChoices = input(
        message: 'Select the Servers:',
        parameters: [
            [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',
            choiceType: 'PT_MULTI_SELECT', // Use PT_MULTI_SELECT for checkboxes
            description: 'Select the Servers',
            filterable: true,
            name: 'Server',
            randomName: 'choice-parameter-5631314456178619',
            referencedParameters: 'Env',
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript',
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [],
                    sandbox: false,
                    script:
                        'return[\'Could not get Environment from Env Param\']'
                ],
                script: [
                    classpath: [],
                    sandbox: false,
                    script:
                        '''
                        if (Env.equals("Dev")){
                            return["devaaa001","devaaa002","devbbb001","devbbb002","devccc001","devccc002"]
                        }
                        else if(Env.equals("QA")){
                            return["qaaaa001","qabbb002","qaccc003"]
                        }
                        else if(Env.equals("Stage")){
                            return["staaa001","stbbb002","stccc003"]
                        }
                        else if(Env.equals("Prod")){
                            return["praaa001","prbbb002","prccc003"]
                        }
                        '''
                ]
            ],
            visibleItemCount: 5
            ]
        ]
    )

    echo "Selected Environment: ${envChoices.Env}"
    echo "Selected Servers: ${serverChoice.Server}"
    
}
```

This is the groovy script code for activrereactiveparameteraizaion

Observation:
At the start of jenkins build it get called,

but I can't see any dropdown option
below attached scrrenshot of o/p:

[image]